# Installing Maven artifacts to local repo programmatically

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

What I have is the need to use a Groovy script or Maven plugin to generate a jar before compile time and then install it to the local repository so it can be used in the compile process (ie the depend will be satisfied by the build process and not downloaded through any external repos).
I have got as far as using a groovy script to create this jar before the compiling / dependency resolution begins.

As the API documentation for working with Maven outside of creating a Mojo is very slim, I would like some pointers to getting this jar into the local repository.

Thanks in advance, md_5.

EDIT: I would also like to have a way of knowing if the artifact is in the maven repo beforehand.

Comment: Please clarify. Is this all during the process of running one single module build in Maven?

Comment: Yes, this is to go in a script / plugin executed during one maven lifecycle.

Comment: @md_5 is there a reason why you can't just setup a Maven repository, using Nexus, Artifactory or Archiva?

Comment: Because I cannot 'legally' distribute this modified jar in question. Instead I plan to simply use a binary patch the original jar to the one I need. I have already done the patch part of it, I just need to get it into the users repo.

Comment: So if I'm reading between the lines correctly, you can legally distribute the unmodified jar but not the modified one.  Therefore you want to provide the unmodified jar to the user as part of the project, then modify it as part of the build process on the user's machine.  Am I close?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use [maven-invoker-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-invoker-plugin/), which starts a new Maven instance, where you generate your artifact, build it, and install into local repo, using native Maven plugins.